# Table Issues in Latex?

Tags: tables

Currently, I am working on a latex document but unfortunately, black cells appear on the head of the table while using table generator.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{B6DBF4} 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Time Shift\\ (hour)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1.5 Rev V\\ (m/s)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2.5 Rev V\\ (m/s)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Time Shift\\ (hour)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1.5 Rev V\\ (m/s)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2.5 Rev V\\ (m/s)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
2                                                                    & 15.1                                                               & 4.2                                                                & -2                                                                   & 14.6                                                               & 3.9                                                                \\ \hline
4                                                                    & 31.1                                                               & 8.7                                                                & -4                                                                   & 27.2                                                               & 7.9                                                                \\ \hline
6                                                                    & 47.7                                                               & 14.1                                                               & -6                                                                   & 39.3                                                               & 12.6                                                               \\ \hline
8                                                                    & 66.9                                                               & 19.3                                                               & -8                                                                   & 53.9                                                               & 17.8                                                               \\ \hline
10                                                                   & 85.9                                                               & 24.9                                                               & -10                                                                  & 67.1                                                               & 22.3                                                               \\ \hline
18                                                                   & 224.4                                                              & 59.8                                                               & -18                                                                  & 113.1                                                              & 55.9                                                               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Any idea?[image]

UPDATE1: table code is added

Comment: Please do _not_ ask one question twice. Register to your account and edit the previous question with a _compilable_ code, not a code snippet.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - please create a [minimum working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with just the table and the minimum number of packages that still demonstrate the problem. It may be an incompatibility with something else in your code. (Add it to the previous question, as JouleV said.)

Comment: As I wrote under an earlier question of yours (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490108/35864) we often ask for a full example document that starts with `\documentclass`, contains the relevant `\usepackage` lines and has a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` environment with the problematic code. Snippets of code without context are often unfortunately not enough to reproduce (and then resolve) the issue you are facing. Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. BTW: If you edit your earlier question with more info, it will automatically be considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see it:

```
...
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
...

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{,mn,mn,n}\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{B6DBF4} 
    \bfseries\shortstack{Time Shift\\ (hour)} & 
    \bfseries\shortstack{1.5 Rev V\\ (m/s)} & 
    \bfseries\shortstack{2.5 Rev V\\ (m/s)} & 
    \bfseries\shortstack{Time Shift\\ (hour)} & 
    \bfseries\shortstack{1.5 Rev V\\ (m/s)} & 
    \bfseries\shortstack{2.5 Rev V\\ (m/s)} \\ \hline
 2 &    15.1 & 4.2  & -2 & 14.6 & 3.9 \\ \hline
 4 &    31.1 & 8.7  & -4 & 27.2 & 7.9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]